# Can i add two independant maven projects into one Project in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I have a GitLab project, and I want to store multiple maven projects (logically related) into that project. Would that be okay in a single GitLab Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GitLab project is just a Git repository with some (very nice!) bells and whistles attached. There's no hard requirement for the entire project to produce one artifact, have a single build process, or even have a build process at all.

The recommended best practice is indeed to have a single Maven project per GitLab project in order to better utilize GitLab's CI tools, but that is not a requirement.